# How to check equality of LinkedHashMaps in Java - also taking the insertion-order into account?

Tags: java, equals, linkedhashmap

I'd like to check the equality of two LinkedHashMaps in Java.

the `equals()`-method is located in `AbstractMap` and only checks if and entry with the same key and value is present in the compared list. Thus, the insertion order is not checked:

```
package com.stackoverflow.tests;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class LinkedHashMapEqualsTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> lhm1 = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    lhm1.put("A", "1");
    lhm1.put("B", "2");
    lhm1.put("C", "3");
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> lhm2 = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    lhm2.put("A", "1");
    lhm2.put("B", "2");
    lhm2.put("C", "3");
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> lhm3 = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    lhm3.put("A", "1");
    lhm3.put("C", "3");
    lhm3.put("B", "2");
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> lhm4 = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    lhm4.put("A", "1");
    lhm4.put("B", "2");
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> lhm5 = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    lhm5.put("A", "2");
    lhm5.put("B", "2");
    lhm5.put("C", "3");

    if(lhm1.equals(lhm1)) {
      System.out.println("Positive control. - SUCCESS");
    }
    if(lhm1.equals(lhm2)) {
      System.out.println("lhm1 does equal lhm2; as expected. - SUCCESS");
    }
    if(lhm1.equals(lhm3)) {
      System.out.println("lhm1 does equal lhm3, although the insert-order is different.");
    }
    if(!lhm1.equals(lhm4)) {
      System.out.println("Negative control 1. - SUCCESS");
    }
    if(!lhm1.equals(lhm5)) {
      System.out.println("Negative control 2. - SUCCESS");
    }

  }

}
```

How can I check if also the insertion order is the same for both compared lists?

Comment: You should override equals method. By default it uses equals implementation of `Abstract Map`. so along with that implementation you need to iterate over the map to check insertion order of the EntrySet.

Comment: If performance isn't that big an issue you could try and create array lists out of the entry sets, e.g. `new ArrayList<>(lhm1.entrySet()).equals(new ArrayList<>(lhm2.entrySet()))`. For lists to be equal their order must be the same and LinkedHashMap's entry set also has insert order so the lists have that order as well. Of course you could just create a method that operates directly on the entry sets.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd probably not override `equals()` of `LinkedHashMap` but provide a helper method, e.g. like this (inspired by `AbstractList#equals(...)`):

```
public static <K, V> boolean linkedEquals( LinkedHashMap<K, V> left, LinkedHashMap<K, V> right) {
  Iterator<Entry<K, V>> leftItr = left.entrySet().iterator();
  Iterator<Entry<K, V>> rightItr = right.entrySet().iterator();

  while ( leftItr.hasNext() && rightItr.hasNext()) {
     Entry<K, V> leftEntry = leftItr.next();
     Entry<K, V> rightEntry = rightItr.next();

     //AbstractList does null checks here but for maps we can assume you never get null entries
     if (! leftEntry.equals(rightEntry))
         return false;
  }
  return !(leftItr.hasNext() || rightItr.hasNext());
}
```

Then you use it like `if( linkedEquals(lhm1, lhm3) )`.

**Edit:**

As per request, another way which yields lower performance (due to multiple unnecessary iterations) but requires to write less code would be to convert the entry sets to lists and compare those, e.g. like this:

```
if( new ArrayList<>(lhm1.entrySet()).equals(new ArrayList<>(lhm3.entrySet()) ) { ... }
```

Comment: You should post your other solution as well.

Comment: I don't like the second solution nearly as much. a) it always does the full iteration of both maps, b) it relies on Map.Entry correctly implementing equals (in fact both versions do that)

Comment: b) is ok, since the equals() contract of Map.Entry is documented, but a) sucks

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd as for a): that's why I didn't post it in the first place ;) - as for b) `Map.Entry` correctly implements `equals`, in fact it's the implementation in `HashMap.Node` which contains `Objects.equals(key, e.getKey()) && Objects.equals(value, e.getValue())` after some basic checks.

Answer (score 2):

A naive way to do this without any extending would be to use the `toString()` output:

```
public static <K,V> boolean equalConsideringInsertionOrder(
  Map<K,V> left, Map<K,V> right){

  return left.toString().equals(right.toString());
}
```

But as pointed out in comments, this version is somewhat iffy. toString() is not meant as canonical format, so it shouldn't be used that way.

A more elaborate, efficient and correct version would be something like this:

```
public static <K, V> boolean equalConsideringInsertionOrder(
        Map<K, V> left, Map<K, V> right) {

    Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> leftIterator = left.entrySet().iterator();
    Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> rightIterator = right.entrySet().iterator();
    while (leftIterator.hasNext() && rightIterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<K, V> leftEntry = leftIterator.next();
        Map.Entry<K, V> rightEntry = rightIterator.next();
        if (!Objects.equals(leftEntry.getKey(), rightEntry.getKey())
                || !Objects.equals(leftEntry.getValue(),rightEntry.getValue())) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return !leftIterator.hasNext() && !rightIterator.hasNext();
}
```

Comment: Uh uh uh... Equal string representations are not the same as equal objects. Two unequal objects are very well allowed to produce the same results in `toString()`.

Comment: @mastov In theory, that's true. But all descendents of AbstractMap are very well-behaved in how they implement toString

Comment: I'm not talking about the Map, I'm talking about the Keys and Values.

Comment: argh, now this is a dupe of Thomas' answer. I swear, I didn't see that one before I wrote mine :-)